# Name of automatic module 'jasperreports' is unstable, it is derived from the module's file name

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, module, package

i have a Java app, using maven, i am with jasperreprots dependency and all works, the problem is the warking on the unstable file name on module-info, i understand the problem, but how can i fix it? how can i use the module with a stable name ?

this is my module-info.java

```
   module TestApp{
        exports com.app.jsp;
        requires jasperreports;

}
```

i am using eclipse.
i could solve it by using classpath but i want to use modulepath

Comment: Is this blocking something?

Comment: all work fine, just the eclipse warning. maybe i should use classpath ?

Comment: Using the classpath would not work as long as you have a `module-info.java` which can only reference modules on the module path. Deleting your `module-info.java` would work. Or see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is shown because the **JAR** you refer as `jasperreprots` module **does not** contain a **`module-info.class` nor an `Automatic-Module-Name: ...`** entry in the `MANIFEST.MF`.

So the module name `jasperreports` is **derived** from the **file name of the JAR**. Renaming the JAR can change the module name breaking your `module-info.java` as `requires jasperreports;` would also need to be adapted to the new JAR file name and then the changed `module-info.java` to be compiled again. That is why the warning says the module name that is automatically derived from the file name of the JAR is unstable.

Nowadays, almost all dependencies contain at least a `MANIFEST.MF` with `Automatic-Module-Name`. Most likely you are using an outdated dependency built for Java 8 or lower.

Comment: so if dont contain a automatic module name i should use it on classpath?

Comment: You can delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_), but if you have a [`module-info.java`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) you can only reference dependencies on the module path, not on the classpath.